# Rails 4 boolean checkbox not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have a model in which I have a boolean attribute, `published`. In my `Post` controller I have added it to my permitted attributes. Like this:

```
params.require(:post).permit([...], :published)
```

My index action that should list all published posts looks like this:

```
def index
    if session[:user_id]
      @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    else
      @posts = Post.where("published = 1").paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
end
```

And lastly my form looks like this:

```
= form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  [...]
  .field
    = f.label :published, "Publicera:"
    = f.check_box :published      
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

Currently no posts is listen on my index page, even if I either the new or updat view checks the checkbox. And I'm not sure how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the query is generated correctly? `log/development.log` will show you the SQL that's executed, and you can always test this against your database independently to verify it's working correctly.

Comment: @tadman My log for my update action shows this: `Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {[...], "published"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Uppdatera inlägg", "id"=>"3"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/3
Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)`. 303, is a problem, right? Not many clues here though...

Comment: You should have some kind of query in there, too, not just the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems be be with my where predicate. This worked:

```
@posts = Post.where(:published => true).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: `"published=1"` is a MySQL thing, so if you're using another database that might not work. `:published => true` should be equivalent on all platforms that support booleans or boolean emulation.